# Why doesn't C-c C-c compile my LaTeX document? Did I set up AUCTeX correctly?

Tags: latex, auctex, osx

This may seem like an odd question but I believe there absolutely should be a standard or most common way to use LaTeX on emacs, and that this community would benefit from owning a complete answer to this question, so here goes.

[This is my first Google hit for "emacs latex mac"](http://www.stefanom.org/setting-up-a-nice-auctex-environment-on-mac-os-x/), which seems to imply AucTeX is the way to go.

[AucTex lives here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) and it is covered in the GNU wiki [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX).

I'm trying installing it now but I'm not sure how out-of-the-box it is. The wiki says:

> C-c C-c to run LaTeX over your document, then, once it has compiled correctly, C-c C-c again to view it, or if it failed to compile correctly, C-c ` to see the errors.

But `C-c C-c` doesn't do this (it brings up a prompt).

Comment: `C-c C-c` would bring up a prompt with different LaTeX programs you could select for the document life-cycle (type `TAB` or `?` when you get the prompt to see the options, which is a generally useful technique for Emacs commands). You can also do `C-h k` and then answer the prompt with the key combination, eg. `C-c C-c` to see what command it is bound to and to read the description of that command.

Comment: There are two (2) common approaches -- there is the built-in solution using `tex-mode.el`; and, there is the non-built-in solution using AUCTeX.  There is a complete **118-page** manual written about AUCTeX -- http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.index.html  And, of course, there are different options for installing the tex sources -- e.g., MacTeX -- https://tug.org/mactex/ There are issues with the `$PATH` that many users need to adjust; e.g., `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))`.  A good answer would be the equivalent of a small book.  :)

Comment: Can you successfully compile a LaTeX document in `Terminal.app` without using Emacs?  If the answer to that question is **"no"**, then figure out how to do that correctly first.  If the answer to that question is **"yes"**, then did you install AUCTeX using `M-x list-packages` and did it install correctly?  If AUCTeX installed correctly, did you try restarting Emacs?  Do you have your `(package-initialize)` statement in your `.emacs` file.  The `$PATH` in Emacs is different than in the terminal, so did you check that to see if `:/usr/texbin` is set correctly?  Are there any error `*Messages*`?

Comment: Here is a link to my own creation that offers a method to quickly generate a `*.pdf` file using AUCTeX on OSX, or *without* using AUCTeX.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911  It also has options for Windows, but I have set it up to detect which of those two systems are being used.  Additional configuration is required.

Comment: What's your question?  Here's the link to the [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.index.html) to get you started.

Comment: @Dan I want to know what series of steps I can take to start using Latex from Emacs. For me this means simple editing of math documents and outputting to PDF. The manual is too much information to be useful quickly (as the emacs manual is too much information to start using emacs). Is that too vague?

Comment: The problem with addressing this question is that readers do not know whether the original poster has the necessary ingredients to create a LaTeX document without using Emacs.  Those raw ingredients are generally beyond the scope of using Emacs, and the original poster will never get it to work correctly in Emacs without it.  Forum participators will spin their wheels trying to find out what's wrong with the Emacs aspect, because they will assume the original poster has already set up the base tex installation correctly.  There are a few threads where upgrades to OSX break symlinks and so on.

Comment: For obtaining latex/tex have a look at http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes first.  There is also useful information on http://tex.stackexchange.com .  AUCTeX needs a tex distribution to be present on the system in order to compile the files.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs comes with a built-in mode to edit (La)TeX documents. You can install AUCTeX as an additional package, either via your operating system's package manager if it's available there, or via Emacs's own package manager [ELPA](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/auctex.html).

You can tell whether you're using AUCTeX by bringing up the major mode documentation with `C-h m` (`describe-mode`). If the first paragraph of the description mentions AUCTeX, you're using AUCTeX, otherwise you're using the built-in support. If you have AUCTeX installed, `.tex` and other TeX documents will open in AUCTeX.

In both the built-in mode and AUCTeX, the key binding `C-c C-c` invokes an Emacs command which prompts you to ask what TeX-related command you want to run. The sentence you quote from the wiki is misleading: you need to press `C-c C-c RET` to invoke the default TeX-related command. With the built-in mode, this runs (PDF)(La)TeX. With AUCTeX, this command is more intelligent and defaults to (PDF)(La)TeX if it looks like your document needs recompiling, or to launching a DVI/PDF viewer if your document looks up to date, or to launching one of a few other commands such as BibTeX if it looks like this is needed. As everywhere in Emacs, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to invoke completion, which will show the possible/predefined commands.